# SQL Server : regular expressions with repetitive pattern

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008

I have a column in my table containing emailId in a format that every character is followed by a `*`.

For example:

```
a*b*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*

a*b*2*d*@*g*m*.*c*m*

j*a*t*i*n*@*g*m*a*i*l*.*c*o*m*

a*3*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*
```

The first character should be an alphabet and rest can be alphanumeric followed by `@' then`*` and so on.

**Why I need this:**
I required to validate the data in the database is as required format or not (mentioned above).
And to find out the rows which do not satisfy the criteria.

I have tried:

```
select * 
from test 
where email like '[a-zA-Z][*][a-zA-Z0-9][*][a-zA-Z0-9][*][@][*]%'
```

Which satisfies:

```
a*b*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*
a*3*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*
```

I have tried:

```
select * 
from test 
where email like '[a-zA-Z][*]([a-zA-Z0-9][*])%'
```

Which satisfies:

```
a*(v*)+s@* which is **INVALID EMAIL ID**
```

I have tried, which usually works with C#:

```
select * 
from test 
where email like '[a-zA-Z][*]([a-zA-Z0-9][*]){2,}%'
```

But it is not working.

Any suggestions/help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: XYProblem. What are you trying to do? (I mean, *why* you want to do this?)

Comment: **Why I need this:** I required to validate the data in the database is as required format or not (mentioned above). And to find out the rows which do not satisfy the criteria.

Comment: [`[a-zA-Z][*](?:[a-zA-Z0-9][*])+@[*](?:[a-zA-Z0-9][*])+\.[*](?:[a-zA-Z0-9][*])+` ?](https://regex101.com/r/jV7vD3/1)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't natively support regular expressions - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx. If a regular expression is the only way to solve your problem, you can add regular expression support with a CLR assembly; there are many examples around on SO and the wider internet.

Comment: Did my answer do what you wanted? If it did, please mark it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Technically `LIKE` isn't a regex thing. It essentially only supports character classes (the things in brackets), wildcards (`_`, unlike the typical `.`), and partial matches within strings (`%like this%`, and omitting either `%` essentially anchors like `^` or `$`).

I know very little SQL, and I'm completely unfamiliar with MS SQL. If I missed anything (your data should be better than mine), let me know. (FYI, the email `a.b.d@gmail.com` is valid, so I have allowed it when properly `*` padded. There are numerous other valid emails that this will reject however, like ones with `+` or `-`.)

```
SELECT email FROM Temp1
WHERE (
       --Starts with alpha
        email LIKE '[a-zA-Z][*]%'
       --Letter after character always *
        AND email NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9.@][^*]%'
       --has an @
        AND email LIKE '%[@][*][a-zA-Z]%'
       --Must have alpha numerics around decimal
        AND email NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9][*][.][*][^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
       --Never 2 @'s
        AND email NOT LIKE '%[@]%[@]%'
       --Never ends with @* or .*
        AND email NOT LIKE '%[@.][*]'
       --Must end with *
        AND email NOT LIKE '%[^*]'
      );
```

I tested with the following command [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31704a/2):

```
CREATE TABLE Temp1 ( email varchar(50) ); 
insert INTO Temp1 (email) Values 
    ('abc*@*gm.*cm'),
    ('abc*@*gm.*co.*uk'), 
    ('ab*2*d*@*gm*.*co.*uk'), 
    ('jatin*@*gmail*.*com*'), 
    ('a*3*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*'),
    ('A*b*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*'),
    ('A*b*2*d*@*g*m*.*c*m*'),
    ('J*a*t*i*n*@*g*m*a*i*l*.*c*o*m*'),
    ('1*a*t*i*n*@*g*m*a*i*l*.*c*o*m*'),
    ('J*a*t*i*n*@*.*'),
    ('A*3*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*')
    ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this RegEx:

```
[a-zA-Z][*]([a-zA-Z0-9][*])+[@][*][a-zA-Z][*]([a-zA-Z0-9][*])+([.][*]([a-zA-Z][*])+)+
```

Here is a [Live Demo](http://regexr.com/3d1pp)

**How It Works**

```
[a-zA-Z][*]         # Letter, followed by * (a*, b*, c*)
([a-zA-Z0-9][*])+   # Letter / Number followed by *, appearing one or more times (2*d*, a*b*)
[@]                 # @ Sign
[*][a-zA-Z][*]      # Letter, followed by * (a*, b*, c*)
([a-zA-Z0-9][*])+   # Letter / Number followed by *, appearing one or more times (2*d*, a*b*)
(
[.][*]              # . followed by * (for TLD)
([a-zA-Z][*])+      # Letter, followed by * (a*, b*, c*), appearing one or more times (a*b*)
)+                  # The TLD (above 2 rules, for .com, .org, .net) can have multiple dots
                    # I.e. (.co.uk, .com.vn, .us.org)
```

Comment: Hey Druzion,

Though your Regex is correctly working in C#. 
But is not working in SQL Server as it is suppose to, Please try the below query in SQL to test the same.
You can see query is not give you any result.

CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    email varchar(50)
);
insert 
INTO #Temp1
(email)
Values ('a*b*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*'),
('a*b*c*@*g*m*.*c*o*.*u*k*'),
('a*b*2*d*@*g*m*.*c*o*.*u*k*'),
('j*a*t*i*n*@*g*m*a*i*l*.*c*o*m*'),
('a*3*c*@*g*m*.*c*m*');

select * from #Temp1 where email like
'[a-zA-Z][*]([a-zA-Z0-9][*])+[@][*][a-zA-Z][*]([a-zA-Z0-9][*])+([.][*]([a-zA-Z][*])+)+'

DROP TABLE #Temp1;

Comment: @user1839184 Oh, so you want the `*` to be optional? You want both `a*b*@g*m*.*c*m*` and `ab*@gm*.cm` to work?

Comment: Hey Druzion, 
I want '*' ab*@gm*.cm should not be considered. '*' is mandatory after every character.

Comment: Yes in the demo it is working. Please execute the following SQL Query in MS SQL Server Management Studio. Which is creating Temporary tableand inserting values. Should show the result with the regex provided:                                        CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ( email varchar(50) ); insert INTO #Temp1 (email) Values ('abc*@*gm.*cm'), ('abc*@*gm.*co.*uk'), ('ab*2*d*@*gm*.*co.*uk'), ('jatin*@*gmail*.*com*'), ('a*3*c*@*gm.*cm'); select * from #Temp1 where email like '[a-zA-Z][]([a-zA-Z0-9][])+[@][][a-zA-Z][]([a-zA-Z0-9][])+([.][]([a-zA-Z][‌​*])+)+' DROP TABLE #Temp1;